# Removing an edge from a strongly connected graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a strongly connected graph with at least $2n-1$ edges. Prove that it's possible to remove an edge such that G will still be strongly connected.

I found this question in discrete math book under "advanced graph" section and tried solving it using Euler's theorem and this corollary:

Let $G$ be a planar simple connected graph with n nodes and e edges. For $e \geq 3$
$$e \leq 3v-6$$

But I can't quite figure out how to use this theorem for strongly connected graphs. I'm not sure if this is the correct approach tho. Any other alternative solutions is very much appreciated.

Comment: Is $n$ the number of vertices?

Comment: No.  n can be any positive integer@Jfischer

Comment: Certainly not. Take $n=1$. Then your graph has $1$ edge . If you remove one edge than your graph has no edges and no matter the number of vertices (assuming he has at least 2) he will be disconnected.

Comment: A strongly connected graph is usually a *directed* graph. Is that what's going on in this problem? Or do you mean something else instead of "strongly connected'?

Comment: Yes. I'm talking about a directed graph. @Misha Lavrov

Comment: you have a point. The question hadn't mentioned anything either so I assumed that n can be any natural number. But i guess you are right. @Jfischer

Comment: When you talk about a directed graph it does not make much sens to employ a theorem on simple graphs. Note that any back and forth between two vertices $v$ and $w$ needs at most $2n-2$ edges (at most $n-1$ to get from $v$ to $w$ and at most $(n-1)$ from $w$ to $v$). But you have $|E|\geq 2n-1$ and you only want to remove 1 edge. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes thank you very much@Jfischer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparison to planar graphs won't fly. Planar graphs are undirected graphs, so you can't apply the theorem. Even if you could, there is nothing saying that $G$ is planar, either.

There's an argument by induction using the following idea.

Let $C$ be a (directed) $k$-cycle in $G$. Then one of two things must hold:

- There is an additional edge between two vertices of $C$. If we delete that edge, $G$ remains strongly connected.
- If we contract all of $C$ to a single vertex, the remainder is a strongly connected graph $G'$ with $n-k+1$ vertices and at least $(2n-1)-k$ edges. Finding an edge to delete in $G'$ will give you an edge to delete in $G$.

(The contraction replaces the $k$ vertices of $C$ by a single vertex $v_C$; every edge $(v,w)$ for $v \in V(C)$ will become an edge $(v_C,w)$, and the same for edges going the other way. We don't keep the edges of $C$. This can create multiple copies of an edge.)

---

As a bonus, by carefully analyzing the proof you get, we can figure out that the result also holds for $2n-2$ edges, except when all the cycles are $2$-cycles. That case corresponds to the directed graphs we get by starting with an undirected tree, and replacing each edge $vw$ by two directed edges $(v,w)$ and $(w,v)$.